# save random data to db without duplication - php

Tags: php, random, save

It is an examination system and I made a random question, my problem is how to save it and identify if it is already saved in the database.
Below is the code for the random, why after I click the next even it doesn't have an action in the FORM it post undefined index "sub" BUT i already declare it at the top. How to save data, if it is random and avoid to duplicate the saved data?

```
<?
$exam_id = $_SESSION['examreference_id'];
$sub_id = $_GET['sub'];
$count=0;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            if(!$con)
            {
            die('Could not connect:'. mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("db_compre",$con);
        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM examquestion_table WHERE examreference_id = '$exam_id' AND subjectreference_id = '$sub_id'");

        while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
            {   
                $count++;   
            }           

        mysql_close($con);?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan  = "2">     <?
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            if(!$con)
            {
            die('Could not connect:'. mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("db_compre",$con);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM examquestion_table WHERE examreference_id = '$exam_id' AND subjectreference_id = '$sub_id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {   
                echo "<tr><td ><label>" . " Your time limit is ".$info['totalTime'] ."&nbsp&nbsp". "second(s)" . "</label></td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td ><label>" . $info['question_data'] . "</label></td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td colspan ='2'><hr size = '5' color = 'orange'></td></tr><tr>";     
                echo "<tr><td colspan  = '2'><input type = 'checkbox' name='answer' onClick='javascript:checkone(0)' value = '100'><label>". $info['choice1_data'] ."</label></td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td colspan  = '2'><input type = 'checkbox' name='answer' onClick='javascript:checkone(1)' value = '100'><label>". $info['choice2_data'] ."</label></td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td colspan  = '2'><input type = 'checkbox' name='answer' onClick='javascript:checkone(2)' value = '100'><label>". $info['choice3_data'] ."</label></td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td colspan  = '2'><input type = 'checkbox' name='answer' onClick='javascript:checkone(3)' value = '100'><label>". $info['choice4_data'] ."</label></td></tr>";
            }
        mysql_close($con);?>
```

Comment: First things first. Apply some grammar rules and punctuation to your question please, it's hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't see where you use the index `sub` at all in your code.

Comment: @jprofitt- it is located at the top part of php file, now i move it inside that part.

Comment: You aren't declaring it there, you're trying to access it. If your URL doesn't contain `sub` this will give you the notice. It needs to be something like `http://www.yoursite.com/page.php?sub=foo` for the variable `$_GET['sub']` to exist.

Answer (score 1):

The question wording is very confusing, but the first sentence says "I made a random question, my problem is how to save it and identify if it is already saved in the database."

To take a stab at that, perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect:'. mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("db_compre", $con); 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM examquestion_table WHERE examreference_id = '{$exam_id}' AND subjectreference_id = '{$sub_id}'");
    list($exists) = mysql_fetch_row($result2);

    if (!$exists)
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO examquestion_table (examreference_id, subjectreference_id) VALUES ('{$exam_id}', '{$sub_id}')");

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I don't see any form or reference to 'sub' in the code you posted, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

---

**EDIT** - OP edited code in question

With your code, you could potentially get a PHP Notice saying that 'sub' is an undefined index in $_GET, which is the case if `$_GET['sub']` is not set.

Check the form that this page is called from. If the `method` property is set to 'POST', then you need to use `$_POST['sub']`.

You could also use `$_REQUEST['sub']` to get it from either, but keep in mind that this checks GET, POST, and COOKIES, so make sure you won't have any conficts before using this method.

I would start with doing this:

```
<?php
    echo "GET:";
    var_dump($_GET);

    echo "<br /><br />POST:";
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

That will show you what data is in each.

Comment: @ga_ra: The PHP Notice will still show until you fix the problem. The code I posted will just help you with figuring out where the problem is so that you can find it and fix it. What is the output that you get when you run my debug code at the beginning of your script?

Comment: GET:array(1) { ["sub"]=> string(1) "3" } POST:array(0) { } is show when I saved and refresh, but when I click the next  GET:array(0) { }
POST:array(0) { }
Notice: Undefined index: sub in C:\xampp\htdocs\compre\answersheet.php on line 57

Comment: So it sounds like when you "click the next", you are not passing 'sub' in the GET array. The GET array gets its values from the URL, so you'll need to call your URL something more like 'answerssheet.php?sub=3', or pass the value via another form.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you pull questions for the database and the user answers them.
You want to be sure that no question will be presented more than once and you want
to save the answer of the visitor as well.

If that's what you mean , than you should create another table which indicates which questions have been asked, the same table will also save the chosen answer.

The main problem is: how to relate the questions to the visitor?
If you have a member-system you should relate the questions to the USER'S ID,
otherwise use a cookie with a random value of microtime() or some unique value.

> +user_answers
>   -id
>   -question_id
>   -chosen_answer
>   -user_uniqe_id

When you pull the questions from the database , use JOIN to make sure that the ID of the question doesn't exists in "user_answers" for the "user_unique_id".

You'll need to create a function which adds the question asked and the chosen choice to this table.
I see you're using js onclick , you need to summon a php file which runs that function.

Comment: thanks for another suggestion, maybe i can add what have you said, you give me more idea.

Comment: you're welcome , try to edit your question and to explain your problem better (just a tip for basic use in Stackoverflow)